# ReactNative Socket.IO : "SocketRocket: In debug mode. Allowing connection to any root cert"

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, socket.io

Trying to connect using **socket.io-client**, with no success.
Not much information about this topic out there, most examples are using localhost...

When using a network sniffer (Charles) to try and trace request, I can see normal HTTP requests, and ReactNative localhost server (When running debug) but do not see my socket connect URL. It does not even trigger.

Receiving this warning on chrome debugger:

"SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert"

**Code:**

```
import Client from "socket.io-client";
const url = "wss://mydomain.general.green/engine.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&token=235353423343"
const socketIOConnOpt = {
  "force new connection": true,
  "reconnection": true,
  "reconnectionDelay": 10000,
  "reconnectionDelayMax": 60000,
  "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "transports": ["websocket"]
};

const socket = new Client(url, socketIOConnOpt);

socket.on("connect", () => {
  Log.info("Connected to socket");
});
socket.on("event", (event) => {
  Log.info("Event from socket" + event);
});
socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  Log.info("Disconnected to socket");
});
socket.on("message", (message) => {
  Log.info("Socket message" + message);
});
```

Running on an iOS simulator.

Comment: In my case, I had to disable the SSL connection. usesSSL == false. you can just try to disable the SSL config according to your config file.

Comment: @RajanMaharjan where should the usesSSL == false be set?

Comment: @coder just add next key in the socketIoConnOpt.

Example:

const socketIOConnOpt = {
  "force new connection": true,
  "reconnection": true,
  "reconnectionDelay": 10000,
  "reconnectionDelayMax": 60000,
  "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "transports": ["websocket"],
  "useSSL": false
};

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Setting usesSSL to false didn't work for me, nor would it be a viable solution for a many production apps if it did work.